# Sequelize - create through multiple association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have three models: `A, B, C` where `A.hasMany(C)`, `B.hasMany(C)`, `C.belongsTo(B)`, `C.belongsTo(A)`.

I want to create all the models through association as stated in Sequelize's docs:

> A.create(data, {
>     include: [{
>       association: B
>     },{
>       association: C
>     } ]
>   })

How can I do this in using Sequelize's association? I tried in a few ways but it failed due to "double" association in C.

Comment: Have you tried something? Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
A.create(data,{
    include : [
       {
          model : B,
          include: [
              model: ...
          ] 
       }
    ]
})
```

But, your A and B models are not associated.

Comment: Also you can include C under A, too

Comment: Thank you, I think you misunderstood me. A and B are not associated to each other. A and B are both associated to C. I'm trying to create in one query using Sequelize syntax  A first => Include B with A_id=> include C with both A_id and B_id.

Comment: hmm, it seems you may use custom query using ```sequelize.where```, ```sequelize.fn```, ```sequelize.col```